# How did Chigurh find the hotel he was staying at?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, no-country-for-old-men

I haven't yet figure out that Chigurh worked for anybody - but I'll have to watch it again.  It's a bit confusing.

What I Do want to know (I must have missed something) is how did Chigurh find the hotel he was staying at in the end where he was waiting for his wife? He kills the bounty hunter, answers the phone and talks to him and then changes his plans where his wife should go.

How did he find him there? since he no longer had the transponder.

Comment: I'd say watch it again, because it's one of those movies that just gets better and better the more you watch it.  I'd also recommend reading the book, which is quite short and exceptionally readable, and will shine light on the film and provide additional insight.  Cormac McCarthy is rare among contemporary literary writers, imo, in that he writes many "genre" books as a vehicle for fundamental, philosophical ideas, in prose that is both fun and accessible to everyone.

Comment: Are you talking about Moss (the guy who found money and was running away from Chigurh) or Wells (the bounty hunter)?

Answer (score 4):

From what I remember about the movie, Chigurh arrived at the hotel after the crime scene was already sealed off and processed/processing by the police. After the police leave, Chigurh goes into the hotel and recovers the money that was hidden in the vent. It was covered throughout the movie that Chigurh has a great tracking skill set. He most likely heard about the crime on the radio, police scanner, TV, etc. and just waited for the room to be clear before he entered. In short, the Mexicans found the hotel room by talking to the mother-in-law; Chigurh found the hotel room later, after it was already communal knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

He (Chigurh) had placed a tracking device in his bag. That's why when he sees the truck outside, he doesn't understand how was he able to track him down so easily, because he was unaware of the tracking device.

Comment: Is that speculation and deduction on your part, or do we see that or see a specific reference to the tracking device?